# HBase/Zookeeper Class Not Found Exception

Tags: cygwin, hbase, apache-zookeeper

I'm running a stand alone instance of HBase on Windows using Cygwin. When a try to start Hbase a get the below exception.  I have HBASE_CLASSPATH set in my hbase-env.sh file( export HBASE_CLASSPATH=/cygdrive/c/cygwin64/usr/local/hbase-0.94.16/lib/zookeeper-3.4.5.jar). Any help would be great. Thanks.

```
127.0.0.1: starting zookeeper, logging to /usr/local/hbase-0.94.16/bin/../logs/hbase-espeelman-zookeeper-PTR-KoPWebDev14.out
127.0.0.1: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/zookeeper/server/quorum/QuorumPeerConfig
127.0.0.1:      at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.HQuorumPeer.main(HQuorumPeer.java:62)
127.0.0.1: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerConfig
127.0.0.1:      at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
127.0.0.1:      at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
127.0.0.1:      at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
127.0.0.1:      at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
127.0.0.1:      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
127.0.0.1:      at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
127.0.0.1:      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
starting master, logging to /usr/local/hbase-0.94.16/bin/../logs/hbase-espeelman-master-PTR-KoPWebDev14.out
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/zookeeper/KeeperException
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainMethod(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: >> using Cygwin     well that's your first problem..

Comment: Hi, were you able to solve this? I am hitting the same issue?